# How to get actual position of sprite and print it in c++ and sfml

Tags: c++, sfml

Im trying to make simple 2d game. I need to print this in console. I tried to do this but it's not working.

```
sf::Vector2f position = entity.getPosition();
std::cout << position  << endl;
```

I also tried

```
p_pos = entity.getPosition();

std::cout << _p_pos  << endl;
```

and it's still not working.

Comment: Well for this to work Vector2f must have overloaded << operator. Also what is the implementation of Vector2f, what exactly does getPosition() do?

Comment: You may know what you mean by "not working", but nobody else does. Be specific.

Comment: `std::cout << _p_pos.x << "x" << _p_pos.y  << std::endl;` ?

Comment: // retrieve the absolute position of the entity
sf::Vector2f position = entity.getPosition(); // = (15, 55)
It's from sfml tut :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...it's not working...

does not help us. Please post the full error.

---

Regardless, I'm assuming that `operator<<(std::ostream&, const sf::Vector2&)` is not defined by default. Therefore, you can print the coordinates of the vector separately:

```
sf::Vector2f position = entity.getPosition();
std::cout << position.x << " " << position.y << "\n";
```

Comment: Thank you so much!